# The meaning of "biting economic sanctions"

Tags: meaning

The full sentence from the Economist is "China is reluctant to impose biting economic sanctions on the authorities in Pyongang,....."

I'm not sure "bite the sanctions" means cancel punishment or stop permission?

Comment: Hi, Ghost, did you try to look up [**biting**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/biting) in the dictionary? **Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) are off-topic**. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: It means sanctions with teeth, and likely to be painful.

Answer (score 4):

*Biting* here is the participle employed as an adjective modifying *economic sanctions*: these are economic sanctions (penalties, punishments) which would "bite", which would inflict severe pain on the authorities in North Korea.

We speak similarly of laws "with teeth": that is, laws which prescribe painful penalties for violations.